Python Papermill - execute_notebook - Azure Python function
I can create an Azure Functions project (V2) - Python 3.11
After publishing all functions work - they all work on my local dev laptop - however there is one function that does not work when hosted as an Azure Function.
papermill ..
I have the python file downloaded, I can verify that it is in the tmp folder where the Azure Function downloads the file, as well as I have the metadata file there < - same as when debugging locally.
however, when i call execute_notebook function in papermill I get this error immediately?
Kernel died before replying to kernel_info
what does this mean? and how can I make this work when running on Azure Function hosted?

these are all the libraries listed in my requirements.txt that is used to publish the azure functions project. azure-functions
kaggle
azure-storage-blob
pyarrow
plotly
papermill
ipykernel
faker
requests
jupyter
ipython

I managed to make Papermill work by installing the kernel each time the function starts up - since I want to keep on using Azure Serverless (consumption plan):
def RunJupyterNotebookPapermill(inputFile, outputFile): 
    inputFile = GetAbsoluteFilePath(inputFile)
    outputFile = GetAbsoluteFilePath(outputFile)

    pm.execute_notebook(
    inputFile,
    outputFile,
    kernel_name="python3"
    )    
    pass 

Here is a more detailed flow, of some of the key elements, which allow me to download notebooks from kaggle, run them in azure serverless function and then push them back to Kaggle, tested it and it is working ;-)
remember to configure KAGGLE_USERNAME and KAGGLE_KEY with your API in local.settings.json - and ALSO in your Azure Functions Project Config in the Portal - or your functions won't show up online until you add those two configuration keys and values.
import logging 
import azure.functions as func 
import os

from kaggle.api.kaggle_api_extended import KaggleApi

import tempfile

import papermill as pm
import subprocess 
import json 



BlueprintJupyter = func.Blueprint() 

@BlueprintJupyter.route(route="KaggleRefresh", methods=['POST'])
def KaggleRefresh(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse: 

    try:
        #no longer required
        #req_body = json.loads(req.get_body().decode())
        #papermill = req_body.get('Papermill')
       
        # install jupyter kernel 
        InstallJupyterKernel()

        # prepare files 
        tempPath = GetTempPath()
        inputFile = GetFilePath(tempPath, "schedule-run-test.ipynb")
        outputFile =  GetFilePath(tempPath, "schedule-run-test-output.ipynb")

        # pull
        KagglePull(tempPath) 

        files = "" + ListFiles(tempPath)
        files = files + "\n" 

        files = files + "\n" + "Absolute Paths:"
        files = files + "\n" + GetAbsoluteFilePath(inputFile)
        files = files + "\n" + GetAbsoluteFilePath(outputFile)

        # execute
        RunJupyterNotebookPapermill(inputFile, outputFile)

        # push 
        KagglePush(tempPath) 

        return func.HttpResponse( 
            f"Hello, This HTTP-triggered function " 
            f"executed successfully."
            f"Files: {files}")         
    except Exception as ex: 
        return func.HttpResponse( 
            f"This HTTP-triggered function failed." 
            f"{str(ex)}" 
            f"Files: {files}",
            status_code=200 
        )    
    
def KagglePull(tempPath): 
    api = KaggleApi()
    api.authenticate()    

    api.kernels_pull('myusername/schedule-run-test', path=tempPath, metadata=True)

    pass 

def KagglePush(tempPath):  
    api = KaggleApi()
    api.authenticate()

    #api.kernels_push(tempPath)
    api.kernels_push_cli(tempPath)
    pass

def RunJupyterNotebookPapermill(inputFile, outputFile): 
    inputFile = GetAbsoluteFilePath(inputFile)
    outputFile = GetAbsoluteFilePath(outputFile)

    pm.execute_notebook(
    inputFile,
    outputFile,
    kernel_name="python3"
    )    
    pass 

def GetTempPath(): 
    temp_dir = tempfile.gettempdir()
    subfolder_name = "tmpnotebook"
    full_path = os.path.join(temp_dir, subfolder_name)
    return full_path 

def GetFilePath(tempPath, fileName): 
    return os.path.join(tempPath, fileName)

def GetAbsoluteFilePath(fileName): 
    return os.path.abspath(fileName)

def ListFiles(tempPath):
    files = ""
    fileList = [] 
    
    for x in os.listdir(tempPath): 
        y = os.path.join(tempPath, x)
        if (os.path.isfile(y)): 
            fileList.append(y)

    files = '' + '\n' + '; \n'.join(fileList)

    return files

def InstallJupyterKernel():
    os.system('pip install ipykernel')
    os.system('python -m ipykernel install --user --name python3')
    pass



You need to install the kernel by visiting Advance tool kudu and SSH'ing into Azure Function app. Make sure you have created your Azure Function app in Premium or Dedicated app service plan for the ssh to work:-
My function app kudu ssh commands to install kernel:-
pip install ipykernel
python -m ipykernel install --user --name jupytersiddhesh

Azure function app > Development Tools > Advanced Tools > Go:-



My Function app code:-
import azure.functions as func
import logging
import papermill as pm
import tempfile
import os
app = func.FunctionApp(http_auth_level=func.AuthLevel.ANONYMOUS)

@app.route(route="http_trigger")
def http_trigger(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
            name = req_body.get('name')
        except ValueError:
            pass

    if name:
        temp_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
        input_notebook = os.path.join(temp_dir, "input_notebook.ipynb")
        output_notebook = os.path.join(os.getenv('HOME', 'D:\\home\\data\\temp'), "output_notebook.ipynb")

        with open(input_notebook, 'w') as file:
            file.write("""
            # Sample Notebook
            print(f'Hello, {name}. This is a sample notebook execution.')
            """)

        pm.execute_notebook(
            input_path=input_notebook,
            output_path=output_notebook,
            parameters=dict(name=name),
            kernel_name='jupytersiddhesh'
        )

        with open(output_notebook, 'r') as file:
            output_content = file.read()
            
        return func.HttpResponse(output_content, status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "Please provide 'name' parameter.",
            status_code=400
        )

Refer my SO answer for the same error.

Hi, thank you will have to try this.

Was hoping to do something using serverless plan, since I do not want to provision something that is called say once a week?

SSH option is not available for consumption based plan, you will have to add the command to install the kernel as script file in your Function code and all it in requirements.txt as ./<file.py>

does this mean i can use serverless consumption plan, but have to run those two lines to install the kernel everytime a call my serverless azure function? will it work?

No, Just install it once and it will be done

I managed to make this work using the serverless consumption plan, no need for a dedicated plan (provided I remember to not run notebooks that require more than 1.5GB ram)

I included this function that I call prior to using Papermill to execute

def InstallJupyterKernel():
os.system('pip install ipykernel')
os.system('python -m ipykernel install --user --name python3')
pass

I see, Thank you for posting your solution for the benefit of community

pleasure, this function that I included to run your suggested script is what made it work and i was happy that this is allowed within an Azure serverless ( consumptionless) python function ;-) def InstallJupyterKernel():
os.system('pip install ipykernel')
os.system('python -m ipykernel install --user --name python3')
pass
